# How to see if PlayerInput action was performed? Unity, New Input System

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

I'm using the new inptu system, and i want a way to see if an input action has been performed (only once, like GetButtonDown).
If I use ".ReadValue()", the if statement returns true not only once, but for as long as the "inventoryAction button" is held down.

```
    private void Awake()
    {
        playerInput = GetComponent<PlayerInput>();
        inventoryAction = playerInput.actions["Inventory"];
    }
    private void Update()
    {
         if (inventoryAction.ReadValue<float>() == 1)
         {
            Debug.Log("inventory key was pressed");
         }
    
    }
```

How do I only get the "performed" part in an if statement (with the new input system)? Is there something like GetButtonDown in the new input system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with version 1.1.1, actions have a [`WasPressedThisFrame`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.1/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.html#UnityEngine_InputSystem_InputAction_WasPressedThisFrame) method which basically does this.

The documentation(linked above) includes the following code snippet:

> ```
> var fire = playerInput.actions["fire"];
> if (fire.WasPressedThisFrame() && fire.IsPressed())
>     StartFiring();
> else if (fire.WasReleasedThisFrame())
>     StopFiring();
> ```

As the code example shows, there are also `WasReleasedThisFrame` and `IsPressed` which are essentially `GetButtonUp` and `GetButton`, respectively.

Note that there are special considerations to make that make them behave differently than `GetButtonX` calls, especially where buttons release and press thresholds are substantially different, or where buttons are pressed and released multiple times in a frame.

[1.1.1 IsPressed docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.1/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.html#UnityEngine_InputSystem_InputAction_IsPressed):

> This method is different from simply reading the action's current `float` value and comparing it to the press threshold and is also different from comparing the current actuation of `activeControl` to it. This is because the current level of actuation might have already fallen below the press threshold but might not yet have reached the release threshold.
>
> This method works with any type of action, not just buttons.
>
> Also note that because this operates on the results of `EvaluateMagnitude()`, it works with many kind of controls, not just buttons. For example, if an action is bound to a `StickControl`, the control will be considered "pressed" once the magnitude of the `Vector2` of the control has crossed the press threshold.
>
> Finally, note that custom button press points of controls (see `pressPoint`) are respected and will take precedence over `defaultButtonPressPoint`.

[1.1.1 WasPressedThisFrame docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.1/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.html#UnityEngine_InputSystem_InputAction_WasPressedThisFrame):

> This method is different from `WasPerformedThisFrame()` in that it is
> not bound to phase. Instead, if the action's level of actuation (that
> is, the level of magnitude -- see `EvaluateMagnitude()` -- of the
> control(s) bound to the action) crossed the press threshold (see
> `defaultButtonPressPoint`) at any point in the frame, this method will
> return `true`. It will do so even if there is an interaction on the
> action that has not yet performed the action in response to the press.
>
> This method works with any type of action, not just buttons.
>
> Also note that because this operates on the results of
> `EvaluateMagnitude()`, it works with many kind of controls, not just
> buttons. For example, if an action is bound to a `StickControl`, the
> control will be considered "pressed" once the magnitude of the `Vector2`
> of the control has crossed the press threshold.
>
> Finally, note that custom button press points of controls (see
> `pressPoint`) are respected and will take precedence over
> `defaultButtonPressPoint`.

Be sure to read the documentation for your version for more information.